# Better way to access the $ref property and parse it's value in JSON.net JsonSchema class

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

For a JSON schema that looks like this:

```
JsonSchema propertyJSch = JsonSchema.Parse(
@"{ ""id"" : ""pet"",
   ""properties"" : {
      ""petLicense"" : {
         ""$ref"" : ""#/definitions/petLicense""
      }
   }
}
"
);
```

I was assuming this would help me get the value of $ref:

```
var petLicValue = propertyJSch.Properties.First().Value;
var petLicValueDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(petLicValue.ToString());
var refvalue = petLicValueDict["$ref"];
```

But this doesn't work at all. Is there any way of doing this?
I'd assume the JSON.Net library would have a way of doing this but turns out it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you should do:

1. Store json as a string value

```html
var json = @"{ ""id"" : ""pet"",
                   ""properties"" : {
                      ""petLicense"" : {
                         ""$ref"" : ""#/definitions/petLicense""
                      }
                   }
                }";
```

2. Deserialize the string using dynamic

```html
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
```

3. This is how you access the property

```html
var r = values["properties"]["petLicense"]["$ref"];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So you're basically suggesting to not use the JsonSchema class at all?

Comment: You can use JsonSchema as well, but the above code might not work. I feel doing it as stated above is a better way. Also, don't forget mark this as answer if it works for you. :)